# Escaping regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, escaping, pcre

I am trying to escape a PCRE in PHP for use in a script. For some reason I can't get it to function when it has been escaped, I've only managed to get it working when the REGEX is given as a form input.

The Regex I'm using is:

```
$pattern = '£((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?£';
```

So far I have tried:

preg_quote(): converts the Regex to the following and throws an error: Â£((http\|ftp\|https):\/\/)\?([\w\-_]+(\?:(\?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@\?\^\=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@\?\^\=%&/~\+#])\?Â£

htmlentities(): gives error:  Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'a'

addslashes(): same as above

mixture of the 3: same as above

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you copy paste the regular expression from somewhere else, and while copying you copy Hidden Junk Characters,  Instead of "pound" symbol, use something else or retype it using your keyboard to fix the issue

Comment: That fixed it! Looks like the pound symbol was the issue, thank you. I had some trouble thinking of a delimiter to use, as the regex uses a lot of symbols.

Comment: I prefer using / or ! as in example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pound symbol was the issue here, replacing it to an exclamation mark solved the problem.
Working expression:

```
$pattern = '!((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?!';
```

For some reason this is working fine with no escape functions.